# SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT name), id, adress from users

Tags: php, sql, count

With PHP I'm trying to run a SQL query and select normal columns as well as COUNT.

```
$sql_str =  "select COUNT(DISTINCT name), id, adress from users";
$src = mysql_query($sql_str);

while( $dsatz = mysql_fetch_assoc($src) ){
    echo $dsatz['name'] . "<br>";
}
```

The problem is that when I have "COUNT(DISTINCT name)," in my query, it will only return the first entry. When I remove it, it will return all matching entries from the db.

I could separate it and do 2 queries, but I'm trying to avoid this due to performance concerns.

What do I make wrong?
thx, Mexx

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this query? It looks like you are mixing two different things.

Comment: Yeah, what are you actually trying to do? Find the number of people with unique names at an address or get a list of users and the total number of them at the same time?

Comment: just drop the count() and do a $counter++ in your while() cycle

Comment: thx for all the answers. will read them tomorrow. just to clarify: yes, i want to do 2 things in 1 query. count the distinct name entries (some appear more than once) and get the values id, address from all rows.

Comment: I agree w/jab11, count the unique values in your loop. No need for two queries, you're already selecting all values. If you order by name, you can easily compare current against previous value and increment the counter when the value changes. If you don't order by name, you'll need to keep an associative array of names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ability to mix normal columns and aggregate functions is a (mis)feature of MySQL.
You can even read why it's so dangerous on MySQL's documentation:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html

But if you really want to mix normal rows and a summary in a single query, you can always use the UNION statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT name), null, null FROM users GROUP BY name --summary row
UNION
SELECT name, id, address FROM users --normal rows
```

Comment: thx for throwing in normal rows vs. summary. That was the point. I now use two queries.

Answer (score 1):

`COUNT()` is an aggregate function, it aggregates against the results of the rest of your query.  If you want to count all distinct names, and not just the distinct names associated with the `id` and `address` that you are selecting, then yes, you will have to run two queries.  That's just how SQL works.

Note that you should also have a `group by` clause when aggregating.  I think the fact that MySQL doesn't require it is horrible, and it encourages really bad habits.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to get :

- one line per user, to get each name/id/address
- one line for several users at the same time, to get the number of users who have the same name.

This is not quite possible, I'd say.

A solution would be, like you said, two queries...

... Or, in your case, you could do the count on the PHP side, I suppose.

ie, not count in the query, but use an additionnal loop in your PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a count() as part of the field list you should group the rest of the fields. In your case that would be

```
select count(distinct name), id, adress from users group by id, adress
```

Comment: if Id is the primary key the aggregation does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(distinct name), id, adress 
from users 
group by id, adress
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to get all your users and the total count in the same query.

Try

```
  select name, id, address, count(id) as total_number 
    from users 
    group by name, id, address;
```